# users and roles tables relationship through middleware parameter laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm developing a user management website using laravel 5.1.

Users are not allowed to register but they are able to see their profiles. Registration can be done only by the admin, so i have two types of users (Admin and normal users).

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8AQLUZ0X9ME
everything was ok until I reached to the User Model

**User table:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**Role table:**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('role_name');
            //
        });
    }
```

**Role Model:**

```
class Role extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'roles';
    protected $fillable = ['role_name'];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
```

**User model:**

```
    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role','role_id');
    }

    public function hasRole($title){
        $user_role = $this->role();
        if(!is_null($user_role)){
            $user_role = $user_role->role_name; //here is the problem with role_name

        }
        return ($user_role===$title)?true:false;
    }
```

In PHPStorm the role_name is highlighted in yellow and it says

> Field 'role_name' not found in class
>   \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Referenced field is not found in subject class.  Note: Check is not
>   performed on objects of type "stdClass" or derived.

I created 3 middlewares Update, Create, and Delete and they all have the same handle function:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $Admin)
    {
        $User = $request->user();
        return ($User->hasRole($Admin))?$next($request):response(view('errors.401'),401);

    }
```

Routes file:

```
Route::get('/users','UserController@index');
Route::post('/users/create',['middleware'=>'create:Admin','uses'=>'UserController@store']);
Route::patch('/users/{id}',['middleware'=>'update:Admin','uses'=>'UserController@update']);
Route::delete('/users/{id}',['middleware'=>'delete:Admin','uses'=>'UserController@destroy']);
```

whenever i open up the create page i got this error:

> "ErrorException in C:\wamp\www\laravelU\project - Copy5\app\User.php
>   line 42: Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$role_name"

I have been dealing with this code for 3 nights i need your help. 
if there is any easier way to achieve my goal without using packages ?

Comment: Which line is line 42??

Comment: User Model:

$user_role = $user_role->role_name; //here is the problem with role_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting an error when trying `$user_role->role_name` is because you're technically looking for the property `role_name` in the `BelongsTo` class.

When trying to access a relationship of an eloquent model you can either use it as a dynamic property i.e.

```
$user_role = $this->role;
```

or

```
$user_role = $this->role()->get();
```

So you can change your hasRole method to something like:

```
public function hasRole($title){

    if(is_null($this->role)){
        return false;
    }

    return $this->role->role_name === $title;
}
```

---

The reason your application is throwing a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is because you are trying to access a `POST` route with a `GET` request. (anytime you navigate to a page using a web browser it will be a `GET` request).

What you should do is change the `Route::post('create' ...` to `Route::get('create'...` ad add something like `Route::post('store'` to submit to.

Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Secondly, you don't need to have 3 different middleware classes if they are just checking if the user is an admin.

Lastly, have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#form-request-validation (including the `Authorizing` section)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ross ! 
here is my routes after editing them:

```
Route::get('/users','UserController@index');
Route::get('/users/create',['middleware'=>'create:Admin','uses'=>'UserController@create']);
Route::post('/users/create',['middleware'=>'create:Admin','uses'=>'UserController@store']);
Route::patch('/users/{id}',['middleware'=>'update:Admin','uses'=>'UserController@update']);
Route::delete('/users/{id}',['middleware'=>'delete:Admin','uses'=>'UserController@destroy']);
```

I get this error when i open up the browser and trying to access the create page :

> "ErrorException in C:\wamp\www\laravelU\project - Copy5\app\User.php
>   line 42: Undefined property:
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$role_name"

in the future, i will add one more role like managers who wont be able to delete users. so i feel it is easier using multiple middlewares but $role_name is pissing me off !

Comment: This is technically a different question and really I should ask you to create a new question, however, if you edit your current question (not the answer) and add the method that includes line 42 of `app\User.php` I can help you.